# Getting string output embedded with \n characters

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

While scraping a website data, i am getting below o/p:

['1 tablespoon\nvegetable or coconut oil\n1 tablespoon\npeeled and minced fresh ginger (from a 1-inch piece)\n2 cloves\ngarlic, minced\n3 tablespoons\nvegan Thai red curry paste, such as Thai Kitchen\n2\nmedium sweet potatoes (about 1 pound total), peeled and cut into 1/2-inch cubes\n1 (15-ounce) can\nchickpeas, drained and rinsed\n1 (13- to 14-ounce) can\nfull-fat coconut milk\n1/2 cup\nwater\n1 teaspoon\nkosher salt\n1/4 teaspoon\nfreshly ground black pepper\n1 (5-ounce) bag\nbaby spinach (about 5 packed cups)\nJuice from 1 medium lime (about 2 tablespoons)\nCooked rice, for serving (optional)']

Where the first element is 1 tablespoon\nvegetable or coconut oil, second is 
1 tablespoon\npeeled and minced fresh ginger (from a 1-inch piece)

So, you can understand that the individual elements are separated by \n and also the individual elements also contains \n. So I am totally confused, how to make a list of the individual ingredient items with no \n there, like:

['1 tablespoon vegetable or coconut oil, 1 tablespoon peeled and minced fresh ginger (from a 1-inch piece), 2 cloves garlic, minced, 3 tablespoons vegan Thai red curry paste, such as Thai Kitchen, Juice from 1 medium lime (about 2 tablespoons), Cooked rice, for serving (optional)']

For the list you can see that, there is no specific pattern like the if we can grab the \n just preceeding any integer as \n is there before Cooked rice, for serving (optional). 
If we replace all the \n then all the occurrences will be replaced. I need to wipe out the \n occurrences from inside individual ingredient and also the \n separator between two ingredients need to be replaced by , as i have shown the expected o/p above.

Actual o/p:

['1 tablespoon\nvegetable or coconut oil\n1 tablespoon\npeeled and minced fresh ginger (from a 1-inch piece)\n2 cloves\ngarlic, minced\n3 tablespoons\nvegan Thai red curry paste, such as Thai Kitchen\n2\nmedium sweet potatoes (about 1 pound total), peeled and cut into 1/2-inch cubes\n1 (15-ounce) can\nchickpeas, drained and rinsed\n1 (13- to 14-ounce) can\nfull-fat coconut milk\n1/2 cup\nwater\n1 teaspoon\nkosher salt\n1/4 teaspoon\nfreshly ground black pepper\n1 (5-ounce) bag\nbaby spinach (about 5 packed cups)\nJuice from 1 medium lime (about 2 tablespoons)\nCooked rice, for serving (optional)']

Expected o/p:

['1 tablespoon vegetable or coconut oil, 1 tablespoon peeled and minced fresh ginger (from a 1-inch piece), 2 cloves garlic, minced, 3 tablespoons vegan Thai red curry paste, such as Thai Kitchen, Juice from 1 medium lime (about 2 tablespoons), Cooked rice, for serving (optional)']

Comment: Whats the url? And  can you please share your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got something close to what you want, hope it helps:

I found 3 separate occasions to replace in the string:

when there's a line break with a number, replace with `", (number)"`

when there's a line break with an uppercase letter, replace with `", (letter)"`

when there's a line break that doesn't fit both of these categories, replace with `" "`

```
import re

text = "['1 tablespoon\nvegetable or coconut oil\n1 tablespoon\npeeled and minced fresh ginger (from a 1-inch piece)\n2 cloves\ngarlic, minced\n3 tablespoons\nvegan Thai red curry paste, such as Thai Kitchen\n2\nmedium sweet potatoes (about 1 pound total), peeled and cut into 1/2-inch cubes\n1 (15-ounce) can\nchickpeas, drained and rinsed\n1 (13- to 14-ounce) can\nfull-fat coconut milk\n1/2 cup\nwater\n1 teaspoon\nkosher salt\n1/4 teaspoon\nfreshly ground black pepper\n1 (5-ounce) bag\nbaby spinach (about 5 packed cups)\nJuice from 1 medium lime (about 2 tablespoons)\nCooked rice, for serving (optional)']"

text = re.sub("\\n(\d)",", \g<1>", text)
text = re.sub("\\n([A-Z])", ", \g<1>", text)
text = re.sub("\\n"," ", text)

print (text)
```

output: ['1 tablespoon vegetable or coconut oil, 1 tablespoon peeled and minced fresh ginger (from a 1-inch piece), 2 cloves garlic, minced, 3 tablespoons vegan Thai red curry paste, such
 as Thai Kitchen, 2 medium sweet potatoes (about 1 pound total), peeled and cut into 1/2-inch cubes, 1 (15-ounce) can chickpeas, drained and rinsed, 1 (13- to 14-ounce) can full-f
at coconut milk, 1/2 cup water, 1 teaspoon kosher salt, 1/4 teaspoon freshly ground black pepper, 1 (5-ounce) bag baby spinach (about 5 packed cups), Juice from 1 medium lime (about 2 tablespoons), Cooked rice, for serving (optional)']